# Excel matching data in columns

Tags: excel

So, I have a around 10,000 values in column A and then about 10 values in column B. I want in column C, for example if cell A1 equals value B1 to B10, then return true, then do this for the 10,000 columns, so if cell A3455 equals any values between B1 and B10. Is there a super quick way?

Comment: Do you really have 10K rows _and_ 10K columns?  This sounds like poor spreadsheet design to me.

Comment: No, just an example!

Answer (score 1):

1) Put that in C1

```
=If(Countif($B$1:$B$10, A1)>0, TRUE, FALSE)
```

2) Copy it down till the last value in column A.
3) Copy the column, and over paste it with values only. 
4) Copy again and paste transposed if you really want 10k columns.
If you actually meant you want TRUE/FALSE all in column C just leave out steps 3+4